# add tabs to existing project

Tags: iphone, tabs, addition

I have a running project with 2 xibs for 2 UIViewControllers (no storyboard). I am looking for the shortest way to add  tabs at the bottom of the screen being able to switch between the views via the tabs.

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHORT ANSWER:

1. In your `MainWindow` add a `UITabBarController`
2. In your `UITabBarController` add `UITabBarItem`s for a `UINavigationController`
3. For each of those `UINavigationController`s set the `RootViewController` to be the `UIViewController`s that you have already

EDIT: More detailed steps, but not necessarily perfect:

1. Find out which view is loaded when your app is loaded (depending on your XCode, this may well be `MainWindow.xib` or its `RootViewController`)
2. Edit the thing from #1 (if defined in code, edit in code; if designed through XIB, edit through XIB) so that it is pointing to a `UITabBarController` (ie `mainWindow.rootViewController = tabBarController` in code)
3. Foreach view controller you want to add, add a `UINavigationController`. If you are using XIB, then just drag new navigation controllers to the tab bar. If you are using code, use `tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController1,navController2,navController3,...]`
4. Foreach of the nav controllers you just created, set its `rootViewController` to be your `ViewController` you want to add.

Comment: can you elaborate on which are UI items added via the UI and which are classes need to be added to the project?